# Difficulty loading data/running model on custom dataset derrived from DNA sequence data - TypeError when attempting to run model

Tags: neural-network, dataset, cnn, pytorch, bioinformatics

I am a student who has some limited experience with keras, and for a new project recently decided to learn how to use pytorch to implement my models. I'm a beginner with both, so apologies in advance for my inexperience, I am doing my best to follow tutorials, but my limited experience combined with most examples being in different uses has resulted in slower comprehension. I'm trying to use NiN blocks as described here (https://d2l.ai/chapter_convolutional-modern/nin.html) to inform my model's architecture.

I have built a custom dataset class for my data, the X data is genetic sequence 256 bases long (i.e. "AGCTGGAGCT..."), so the resulting array after one-hotting to four channels for each of the four bases looks like `[[[1,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0]...], [0,0,1,0], ...]]` and has shape 48,976, 256, 4. I read that Conv1d looks for channels first, so I permuted the channels in the dataset's tensor to read in that way, resulting in `torch.Size([48976, 4, 256])`. The Y data is 2 values for a given sequence of X, ESC and TSC, each numeric values derived from other source data. The dataset code is as follows:

```py
device = "cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"

def onehotseq(dataset, input_shape):
    
    onehot = np.zeros(input_shape)
    
    for i in range(0, dataset.shape[0]):
        seq = dataset.iloc[i,1]
    
        for c in range(0,len(seq)):
            if (seq[c] == "A"):
                onehot[i,c,:] = [1,0,0,0]
            elif (seq[c] == "C"):
                onehot[i,c,:] = [0,1,0,0]
            elif (seq[c] == "G"):
                onehot[i,c,:] = [0,0,1,0]
            elif (seq[c] == "T"):
                onehot[i,c,:] = [0,0,0,1]
    
    return onehot

            
            
class EpiDataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
    
    def __init__(self, Seq_filepath="path_to_sequence_data", Y_data_filepath="path_to_output_data"):
        
        self.seq_data = pd.read_csv(Seq_filepath, sep="\t", header=None)
        
        self.seq_data.rename(columns={0:"id", 1:"seq"}, inplace=True)
        
        self.y_data = pd.read_csv(Y_data_filepath, sep="\t", header = 0)
        
        self.y_data["ESC"] = np.log2((self.y_data["ESC.H3K27ac"].values+1)/(self.y_data["ESC.input"].values+1))
        self.y_data["TSC"] = np.log2((self.y_data["TSC.H3K27ac"].values+1)/(self.y_data["TSC.input"].values+1))
        
        self.dataset = self.seq_data.merge(self.y_data, on="id")
        
        self.list_IDs = self.dataset["id"]
        
        self.seq = self.dataset["seq"]
        
        self.esc = self.dataset["ESC"]
        
        self.tsc = self.dataset["TSC"]
        
        self.input_shape = (self.dataset.shape[0], 256, 4)
        
        self.onehotseq = onehotseq(self.dataset, self.input_shape)
        
        self.tensorX = torch.from_numpy(self.onehotseq)
        
        self.tensorX = self.tensorX.permute(0, 2, 1)
        
        self.labels = self.dataset[["ESC","TSC"]].to_numpy()
        
        self.tensorY = torch.from_numpy(self.labels)
        
        
    
        
    def __len__(self):
                return len(self.list_IDs)
                
    def __getitem__(self, index):
                
                ID = self.list_IDs[index]
                
                seq = self.seq[index]
                
                esc = self.esc[index]
                
                tsc = self.tsc[index]
                
                return {
                    
                    "ID: ": ID,
                    "sequence: ": seq,
                    "ESC: ": esc,
                    "TSC: ": tsc
                }
```

This all seems to work as intended, and I was able to design a Module class, which also seems to be functionally correct, but I get a type error whenever I try to use the model. The code and error are:

```py
def nin_block(out_channels, kernel_size, padding="same"):
    
    return nn.Sequential(
        
        nn.LazyConv1d(out_channels, kernel_size, padding),
        
        nn.ReLU(),
        
        nn.LazyConv1d(out_channels, kernel_size=1), nn.ReLU(),
        
        nn.LazyConv1d(out_channels, kernel_size=1), nn.ReLU()
    
    
    )

class NeuralNetwork(nn.Module):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super(NeuralNetwork, self).__init__()
        
        self.flatten = nn.Flatten()
        
        self.NiN = nn.Sequential(
                nin_block(32, kernel_size=11,padding="same"),
        
                nn.MaxPool1d(3, stride=2),
        
                nin_block(64, kernel_size=4, padding="same"),
        
                nn.MaxPool1d(3, stride=2),
        
                nin_block(128, kernel_size=4, padding="same"),
        
                nn.MaxPool1d(3, stride=2),
        
                nin_block(256, kernel_size=3, padding="same"),
        
                nn.MaxPool1d(3, stride=2),
        
                nn.Dropout(0.4),
        
                nin_block(4, kernel_size=3, padding="same"),
        
                nn.AdaptiveAvgPool1d(2),
        
                nn.Flatten(),
        )
        
    def forward(self, x):
            
        x = self.flatten(x)
            
        logits = self.NiN(x)
            
        return logits
```

Error message, resulting from running `model = NeuralNetwork().to(device)` and then

`logit = model(x.tensorX)`

```py
TypeError: conv1d() received an invalid combination of arguments - got (Tensor, Parameter, Parameter, tuple, tuple, tuple, int), but expected one of:
 * (Tensor input, Tensor weight, Tensor bias, tuple of ints stride, tuple of ints padding, tuple of ints dilation, int groups)
      didn't match because some of the arguments have invalid types: (Tensor, !Parameter!, !Parameter!, !tuple!, !tuple!, !tuple!, int)
 * (Tensor input, Tensor weight, Tensor bias, tuple of ints stride, str padding, tuple of ints dilation, int groups)
      didn't match because some of the arguments have invalid types: (Tensor, !Parameter!, !Parameter!, !tuple!, !tuple!, !tuple!, int)
```

My question is, what am I doing wrong either in building my module or dataset, or am I missing a step? The data loaded in is the prepared data for initial exploration/training of different model architectures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get help off-site, and the issue was feeding "same" into padding at the wrong stage. The correct code would be:

```py
def nin_block(out_channels, kernel_size, padding):
    
    return nn.Sequential(
        
        nn.LazyConv1d(out_channels, kernel_size, padding=padding),
        
        nn.ReLU(),
        
        nn.LazyConv1d(out_channels, kernel_size=1), nn.ReLU(),
        
        nn.LazyConv1d(out_channels, kernel_size=1), nn.ReLU()
    
    
    )

class NeuralNetwork(nn.Module):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super(NeuralNetwork, self).__init__()
        
        self.flatten = nn.Flatten()
        
        self.NiN = nn.Sequential(
                nin_block(32, kernel_size=11,padding="same"),
        
                nn.MaxPool1d(4, stride=2),
        
                nin_block(64, kernel_size=4, padding="same"),
        
                nn.MaxPool1d(4, stride=2),
        
                nin_block(128, kernel_size=4, padding="same"),
        
                nn.MaxPool1d(4, stride=2),
        
                nin_block(256, kernel_size=4, padding="same"),
        
                nn.MaxPool1d(4, stride=2),
        
                nn.Dropout(0.4),
        
                nin_block(4, kernel_size=4, padding="same"),
        
                nn.AdaptiveAvgPool1d(2),
        
                nn.Flatten(),
        )
        
    def forward(self, x):
            
        x = self.flatten(x)
            
        logits = self.NiN(x)
            
        return logits
```

I'm still troubleshooting some other errors/issues, but marking this as closed given the specified error has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

feel free to checkout this articles:

Machine Learning Applications in Genomics Life Sciences by Ernest Bonat, Ph.D.
https://ernest-bonat.medium.com/machine-learning-applications-in-genomics-life-sciences-by-ernest-bonat-ph-d-83598e67ccbc

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/88590)